# Linker Error While Trying to Create Linked List Stack

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, stack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)
>   [Undefined symbol on a template operator overloading function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150412/undefined-symbol-on-a-template-operator-overloading-function)

For my school assignment, I need to make a program that makes a stack using a linked list. I keep getting linker errors though (specifically: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Stack::Stack(void)" (??0?$Stack@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main 1>C:\Users\devon.taylor\Desktop\New folder\Debug\PA3.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals)

Here is my code:

Header:

```
template <class T>
class  Stack
{
public:
    Stack();
    Stack(T data);
    ~Stack();
    void push(T data);
    T pop();
    void display();
    bool isEmpty();
    bool isExist(T searchKey);

private:
    Stack<T> *top;
    Stack<T> *next;
    T mData;
};
```

Functions:

```
#include "stack.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack()
{
    top=NULL;
}

template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(T data)
{
    mData = data;
    pNext = NULL;
}

template <class T>
Stack<T>::~Stack()
{

}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(T data)
{
   Stack *ptr;
   ptr=new Stack<T>;
   ptr->mData=data;
   ptr->next=NULL;

   if(top!=NULL)
   {
      ptr->next=top;
   }
   top=ptr;
   cout<<"\nNew item inserted to the stack";
}        

template <class T>
T Stack<T>::pop()
{


}
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::display()
{

}
```

Main Function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stack.h"

using namespace std;

void main ()
{
    Stack<int>* stack;
    stack = new Stack<int>;
    //stack->push(19);



    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need to test whether `top` is `NULL` when you are pushing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must implment template functions in the header file for the linker to pick it up. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)  for more details.

Also, look at the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates-defn-vs-decl.html) for more details.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: See also this FAQ: [How can I avoid linker errors with my template classes?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/separate-template-class-defn-from-decl.html)

Comment: @user1698667 I updated my answer with extra links - please read those. You'll be better off with those detailed explanations than with me trying to write up a complete answer for you. :)