# Problems with template in c++

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undefined symbol on a template operator overloading function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150412/undefined-symbol-on-a-template-operator-overloading-function)

Here are my source code.
In `Number.h`

```
#ifndef NUMBER_H
#define NUMBER_H

#include <iostream>
using std::istream;
using std::ostream;

template <class T> class Number;

template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Number<T>&);

template <class T>
istream& operator>>(istream&, Number<T>&);

template <class T>
class Number{
public:
    Number(const T &n)  :i(n) {}
    Number()            :i(0) {}
    T& operator+(const Number&rhs) const;
    T& operator-(const Number&rhs) const;
    T& operator*(const Number&rhs) const;
    T& operator/(const Number&rhs) const;
    friend ostream& operator<< <T> (ostream& , const Number<T>&);
    friend istream& operator>> <T> (istream& , Number<T>&);
private:
    T i;
};

#endif
```

And in `Number.cpp`

```
#include "Number.h"

template<class T> 
T& Number<T>::operator+(const Number&rhs) const
{
    return i+rhs.i;
}

template<class T> 
T& Number<T>::operator-(const Number&rhs) const
{
    return i-rhs.i;
}

template<class T> 
T& Number<T>::operator*(const Number&rhs) const
{
    return i*rhs.i;
}

template<class T>
T& Number<T>::operator/(const Number&rhs) const
{
    return i/rhs.i;
}

template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream&os , const Number<T>&rhs)
{
    return os<< rhs.i;
}

template<class T>
istream& operator>>(istream&is , Number<T>&rhs)
{
    return is >> rhs.i;
}
```

I cannot find out why there is

```
undefined reference to `std::istream& operator>><double>(std::istream&,Number<double>&)'
undefined reference to `Number<double>::operator+(Number<double> const&) const'
```

errors so on so forth

Comment: [Same old C++ templates' story](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html)

Comment: Also described under the general undefined-references question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574417/777186

Answer (score 2):

Use .hpp for template and you can't return reference on a temporary object.

number.h

```
#ifndef NUMBER_H
#define NUMBER_H

#include <iostream>
using std::istream;
using std::ostream;

template <class T> class Number;

template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Number<T>&);

template <class T>
istream& operator>>(istream&, Number<T>&);

template <class T>
class Number{
        public:
                Number(const T &n)  :i(n) {}
                Number()            :i(0) {}
                T operator+(const Number&rhs) const; // Error Here return T not T&
                T operator-(const Number&rhs) const;
                T operator*(const Number&rhs) const;
                T operator/(const Number&rhs) const;
                friend ostream& operator<< <T> (ostream& , const Number<T>&);
                friend istream& operator>> <T> (istream& , Number<T>&);
        private:
                T i;
};

#include <number.hpp>

#endif
```

number.hpp

```
#ifndef NUMBER_HPP
#define NUMBER_HPP

template<class T> 
T
Number<T>::operator+(const Number& rhs) const
{
        return i + rhs.i;
}

template<class T> 
T
Number<T>::operator-(const Number&rhs) const
{
        return i-rhs.i;
}

template<class T> 
T
Number<T>::operator*(const Number&rhs) const
{
        return i*rhs.i;
}

template<class T>
T
Number<T>::operator/(const Number&rhs) const
{
        return i/rhs.i;
}

template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream&os , const Number<T>&rhs)
{
        return os<< rhs.i;
}

template<class T>
istream& operator>>(istream&is , Number<T>&rhs)
{
            return is >> rhs.i;
}

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <number.h>

    int
    main(int, const char**)
    {
        Number<double>  value(1);
        Number<double>  add(3);

        std::cout << value + add << std::endl;
        std::cout << value * add << std::endl;
        std::cout << value - add << std::endl;
        std::cout << value / add << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The definitions of all those member functions need to be available to any translation unit that instantiates the template. Imagine a file that includes `Number.h` and attempts to use `Number<int>`. The compiler then needs to generate all of the code for `Number` instantiated with `T` as `int`. How can it do that if it's only seen `Number.h`? It doesn't know the definition of the member functions.

The fix is to put the definitions of your member functions (everything from `Number.cpp`) in `Number.h`. Alternatively, some people like to name `Number.cpp` as `Number.tpp` and, instead of `#include "Number.h"` in `Number.cpp`, put `#include "Number.tpp"` at the *bottom* of `Number.h` - basically inverting the inclusion so that the header always includes the implementation.

Comment: And could you explain why `#include "Number.h"` is more common in situations when there is `template`

Comment: @user1668903 I don't really understand the question, I'm afraid. Whenever you instantiate a template, for example `Number<int>`, the compiler needs to be able to generate the class `Number` with all occurrences of `T` replaced with `int`. To do that, it needs to be able to see all of the code for `Number`, so the header file must contain both the header and the implementation.

Comment: Sorry , I mean that why people won't always `#include "Number.cpp"` in `Number.h` rather than `#include "Number.h"` in `Number.cpp`

Comment: @user1668903 Because a normal implementation file (when it is not a template implementation) needs to be compiled separately. For example, if you have a class `T` that is not templated and there are two files `T.h` and `T.cpp`, you will at some point compile `T.cpp`, which must include the definition of the class from `T.h`. If `T.cpp` doesn't include `T.h`, it won't compile because there will be no class definition. But with your template implementation, `Number.cpp`, it does not need to be compiled separately. In fact, it needs to be included in every translation unit that makes use of it.